# Why NPM CLI creates two identical tokens?

Tags: npm, duplicates, token, npm-cli

I was trying the NPM cli and I ran 2 times the command `npm create token --read-only` after having logged in. The result is that now I have 2 completely identical tokens that I'm not able to manage, neither delete, since the CLI replies with a `Token ID "<TOKEN_HERE>" was ambiguous, a new token may have been created since you last ran "npm token list".`

How can I clean this situation? And why does this happen? Shouldn't the CLI be responsible of assigning UNIQUE IDs?

**EDIT**: A screenshot here

[image]

Comment: If you run `npm token list`, do the tokens have the same IDs?

Comment: Exactly, same ids. Very weird situation. I added a screenshot

Comment: Very odd indeed! Thanks for adding the screenshot.